# Better way to receive a json response

Tags: jquery, json

I am having some problems to receive a JSON response. This is the POST response:

```
{
    "id": xxxxx,
    "name": "xxx",
    "description": null,
    "latitude": null,
    "longitude": null,
    "created_at": "2015-11-28T12:52:07Z",
    "elevation": null,
    "last_entry_id": null,
    "ranking": 15,
    "metadata": null,
    "username": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "tags": [],
    "api_keys": [
        {
            "api_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "write_flag": true
        },
        {
            "api_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "write_flag": false
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is my function in jQuery:

```
function Thingspeak(){
    var API = $('#API_Key').val();
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "https://thingspeak.com/channels.json",  
        data: {api_key: API, name: 'test', field1: 'tm', field2: 'hm', field3: 'bn'},  
        success: function(data) {  
            var id = data.id;
            var API_r = data.api_keys[0][0];
            var API_w = data.api_keys[1][0];
            console.log(id+": "+API_r+" "+API_w)
        }  
    });  
}
```

I receive the channel_id perfectly, but for the api_keys, I have tried to looking for some ways to receive but without any luck. I think is a very simple question, but I am totally stuck with this.

Comment: There's no `data.api_key`, there can be `data.api_keys`

Comment: That's no the problem, I've changed that and the error still there. Is a problem with the way of calling it, I think

Comment: `error still there` What error?

Comment: Well error, is that I cannot receive those values and store into API_r or API_w, therefore the way of calling I thing is wrong: `data.api_keys[1][0];`. Because I want to store some values of the response into variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.api_keys` is an **array** of objects.

Sure, you can access first element of `array` with `[0]`.
But if you print it:

```
console.log( data.api_keys[0] );
```

you will see that `data.api_keys[0]` is an **object** with 2 props - `api_key` and `write_flag`. So proper code should be:

```
console.log( data.api_keys[0].api_key );
// or
console.log( data.api_keys[0]["api_key"] );
```

Comment: That's the problem, thank so much, I cannot call it using [0][1]. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
var API_r = data.api_keys[0].api_key;
var API_w = data.api_keys[1].api_key;
```